# Is there a way to view more columns in pandas. It only lists the first and the last columns

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas displays only the first and the last columns along with id. All other columns in the middle and their values are displayed as '...' . Is there a way to list more columns?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From seeing the `data.corr()` in your code, it is clear that you are talking about pandas. You can adjust the display parameter to choose your preference.

```
pd.set_option('display.height', 100)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 20)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 40)
pd.set_option('display.width', 100)
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about Pandas. If so you can adjust the parameters with

`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)  # or whatever number you want`